# Grails show url content in template (like frame src)

Tags: spring, grails, frame

I hava a Grails app and I want to make use of the Spring Security User Admin Screen. The screen can be accessed via the url

```
localhost:8080/user
```

Since I am not working with urls, but with templates (url always remains localhost:8080), but users can navigate via navbar und templates are loaded, I want to render the url localhost:8080/user into a template. I tried to render a template that contains

```
<frame src="localhost:8080/user">
```

but Grails didn't really like this.
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by grails did not really liked it? If you are getting any error post it.

Comment: IntelliJ says "frame is deprecated" and the whole frame-statement is not executed

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an iframe instead of a frame.

I would also use the Grails `createLink` tag (see http://www.grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Tags/createLink.html) to generate the src attribute value. This would ensure the src has the correct context root, port number, etc...

```
<iframe src="${createLink(controller: 'user', absolute: true)}" />
```